# How do curried functions work in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell. I got to know that any function in Haskell can take only one argument. So, if you see a function `max 2 4`; it actually is `(max 2) 4`. What they say is that 1st `2` is applied (as a parameter) to `max` which returns a functions, that takes `4` as the parameter. What I fail to understand is what happens when 2 is applied to max? What does it mean that it returns a function called `(max 2)`?

Let me give another example, to make my question more clear. Take this function: `multiply x y x = x*y*z`. They say it actually is evaluated this way: `((multiply x) y) z`. Now I give this input: `multiply 2*4*5`
How is this evaluated?

```
multiply 2
```

returns `(multiply 2)` and 4 is applied as parameter:

```
(multiply 2) 4
```

Now what does this return -- `((multiply 2) 4)` or `multiply 8`? If it multiplies 4 and 2 at this step, how does Haskell know that it has to do that (because the function can multiply only 3 parameters)?

Comment: When you call `(multiply 2) 4`, the resulting value is `(multiply 2) 4`, or more explicitly `\x -> multiply 2 4 x`. No additional evaluation takes place at this stage because it can’t. Once a function call is fully saturated (and its value is demanded, since Haskell is lazy, but that doesn’t have to do with currying), then and only then will the function be applied.

Comment: When you have "`multiply 2*4*5`", do you mean "`multiply 2 4 5`"?

Comment: The Haskell report doesn't specify what happens if `miltiply` is given two argument.  It might very well do some reduction with two argument, but I don't know of any implementation (of full Haskell) that does that.

Comment: Also, Haskell is not lazy, it's non-strict.

Comment: If you’re familiar with JavaScript: `max = function(x) { return function(y) { return x <= y ? y : x; }; };`, then `max(2)` is an anonymous function whose closure contains one value, `2`, and `max(2)(4)` is `4`. The same is true in Haskell, although for performance reasons, GHC doesn’t allocate a closure when you fully apply a function.

Comment: `multiply 8 :: Num a => a -> a -> a`, but `(multiply 2) 4 :: Num a => a -> a`.

Comment: @augustss : Thanks. Of other comments and answers, I could relate more to your 1st comment. But how hashkell has to do something when multiply is supplied with less than 3 arguments right? Otherwise how can I try to understand this process of carried functions. Also can you please explain your second comment. As far as I have read, hashkell is lazy! It would be awesome if you could write an answer instead of comment:)

Comment: @Ashwin The difference between lazy and non-strict is somewhat subtle.  The word "lazy" refers to a particular implementation technique for evaluating programs, whereas "non-strict" refers to the semantic property of how the programs behave.  So a lazy implementation is non-strict, but there are other ways to implement a language that make them non-strict.  Saying that Haskell is lazy would have stopped other implementation techniques being able to claim that they are true Haskell.

Comment: @Ashwin Typically Haskell implementations create some kind of closures when there are not enough arguments, so `multiply 2 4` will create a closure that when called (with one argument) will know call `multiply` with 2, 4, and the third argument.  But it's perfectly allowed for the `multiply 2 4` to return `\ z -> 8*z`, where the function could be represented by, e.g., combinators, or maybe even machine code generated at run time.

Answer (score 2):

Just think it mathematically: suppose there is a function taking two variables: `f(x, y)`. Fix `x=2` would give you a new function with one variable: `g(y)=f(2, y)`

If `f(x, y) = max(x, y)` which gives the maximum of x and y, `g(y) = f(2, y) = max(2, y)` gives the maximum of 2 and y.

For `f(x, y, z) = x * y * z`, `g(y, z) = f(2, y, z) = 2 * y * z`, and `h(z) = g(4, z) = f(2, 4, z) = 2 * 4 * z`.

Also you can fix x=2 and z=4 to form `p(y) = f(2, y, 4)`. In Haskell it is

```
\y -> multiply 2 y 4
```

For the implementation, Haskell would not actually multiply 2 and 4 because it's lazy evaluated. That is, it would not compute a value until it has to.